# Turn off list reflection in Numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to accelerate my code using Numba. One of the arguments I'm passing into the function is a mutable list of lists. When I try changing one of the sublists, I get this error:

> Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
>   cannot reflect element of reflected container: reflected list(reflected list(int64))

I don't actually care about reflecting changes I make to the native list into the original Python list. How do I go about telling Numba not to reflect the changes? The documentation is pretty vague regarding list reflection in Numba.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting directly from [the docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#list-reflection):

> In nopython mode, Numba does not operate on Python objects. list are
> compiled into an internal representation. Any list arguments must be
> converted into this representation on the way in to nopython mode and
> their contained elements must be restored in the original Python
> objects via a process called reflection.
>
> Reflection is required to maintain the same semantics as found in
> regular Python code. However, the reflection process can be expensive
> for large lists and it is not supported for lists that contain
> reflected data types. **Users cannot use list-of-list as an argument
> because of this limitation.**

Your best bet would be to give a 2D numpy array of shape `len(ll) x max(len(x) for x in ll)`, ll being the list of lists. I myself use something like this to achieve this, and then pass the `arr, lengths` to the njit compiled function:

```
def make_2D_array(lis):
    """Funciton to get 2D array from a list of lists
    """
    n = len(lis)
    lengths = np.array([len(x) for x in lis])
    max_len = np.max(lengths)
    arr = np.zeros((n, max_len))

    for i in range(n):
        arr[i, :lengths[i]] = lis[i]
    return arr, lengths
```

HTH.

Comment: Indeed, the passed argument lis is not altered in any way in your function hence should not be considered 'reflected' by numba - despite that, it still throws very annoying deprecation warnings: 'NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: 
Encountered the use of a type that is scheduled for deprecation: type 'reflected list' found for argument 'lis' of function 'make_2D_array'.'. Apart from suppressing all the deprecation warnings, any idea of how to shut these off?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass list of list parameter to numba, you should use numpy array instead of original Python list. Numba raise reflection error because of the not supported list features. You can compare the two examples below:

This one is getting the same error:

```
TypeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
cannot reflect element of reflected container: reflected list(reflected list(int64))

import numba

list_of_list = [[1, 2], [34, 100]]


@numba.njit()
def test(list_of_list):
    if 1 in list_of_list[0]:
        return 'haha'

test(list_of_list)
```

Smooth running version is;

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np


@njit
def test():
    if 1 in set(np_list_of_list[0]):
        return 'haha'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_list = [[1, 2], [34, 100]]
    np_list_of_list = np.array(list_of_list)
    print(test())
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be some ways to handle such reflected data structures; here I will show it using *NumPy*, *Numba*, and *Awkward* libraries; As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import awkward as ak

list_uniform = [random.sample(range(80), 20) for i in range(1000000)]
list_nonuniform = [random.sample(range(80), random.randint(1, 40)) for i in range(1000000)]

@nb.njit  # ("void(ListType(ListType(int64)))")
def test(jitmatrix):
    _total = 0
    for i in range(len(jitmatrix)):
        for j in range(len(jitmatrix[i])):
            _total += jitmatrix[i][j]
    return _total
```

**1. Uniform structures:**

If all inner lists have the same length, so the best choice, AIK, is to

- Convert the list to a NumPy array for using by numba njit decorators:

```
matrix_np_uniform = np.array(list_uniform, dtype=np.int32)
```

***the following ways can be used for uniform structures, too:***

**2. Nonuniform structures:**

If we are facing to a list that contains a lot of lists that are not the same in lengths (*nonuniform structures*), so, we can handle this problem in the following ways:

- Converting the all lists to numba typed lists:

```
nb_list = nb.typed.List
matrix_nb = nb_list(nb_list(i) for i in list_nonuniform )  # --> ListType[ListType[int64]]
```

- Converting the all lists to numpy arrays in a numba typed list:

```
matrix_np = nb_list(np.array(i) for i in list_nonuniform )
```

or in a little faster way using `np.fromiter`:

```
matrix_np = nb_list(np.fromiter(i, dtype=np.int64) for i in list_nonuniform)
```

- Import the list in numba-compatible way using other libraries e.g., **awkward**; AIK, it won't need signatures because stores datatypes internally and it uses some broadcasting and can be utilized for ragged arrays/lists in NumPy manners ([read more](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward)):

```
matrix_ak = ak.Array(list_nonuniform )
```

### Benchmarks

Based on my little experiences around the prepared data volume:

**1. For uniform structured ones:**

- Time for converting the lists to numba compatible ones:

```
NumPy (~1.3 Sec) < Awkward (~3.8 Sec) <<< Numba (~1.5 Min)
```

- Time for function execution:

```
NumPy (~21 ms) < Awkward (~31 ms) <<< Numba (~503 ms)
```

**2. For nonuniformed structured ones:**

- Time for converting the lists to numba compatible ones:

```
Awkward (~3.8 Sec) < NumPy (~5 Sec) <<< Numba (~1.5 Min)
```

- Time for function execution:

```
Awkward (~40 ms) < NumPy (~100 ms) <<< Numba (~513 ms)
```