# Numba v0.44: cannot reflect element of reflected container

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I am new to `numba` and am struggling at every turn to get what I think is simple to work in `nopython` mode.

For example, inspired by this question [coalescing-ranges](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222978/coalescing-ranges-that-have-the-same-label) I have written the following function:

```py
@njit
# @jit
def coalesce(ranges):
    coalesced = []
    for i, (label_a, start_a, stop_a) in enumerate(ranges):
        append_flag = True
        for j, (label_b, start_b, stop_b) in enumerate(coalesced):
            if label_a != label_b: # not of same type
                continue
            elif stop_a < start_b: # a does not start and then overlap b
                continue
            elif stop_b < start_a: # b does not start and then overlap a
                continue
            else:
                # same type and overlap, merge into i, do not append
                append_flag = False
                coalesced[j] = [label_a, min([start_a, start_b]), max([stop_a, stop_b])]
                break
        if append_flag:
            coalesced.append([label_a, start_a, stop_a])
    return coalesced
```

It assumes that it is passed in a list of lists. Each sub list consists of only integers `[type, start, stop]` and this function is mentioning to merge similar typed ranges which overlap e.g.:

```
[
    [1, 10, 100],
    [0, 50, 75],
    [1, 50, 150],
    [0, 10, 100],    
    [0, 200, 300],    
    [0, 15, 150]
]
# becomes
[
    [0, 10, 150],
    [0, 200, 300],
    [1, 10, 150]
]
```

This function works with `@jit` (although it spits out a ton of warnings).
When calling this function with `@njit` and the above list:

```
TypeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
cannot reflect element of reflected container: reflected list(reflected list(int64))
```

I have no idea what this means or why this fails.

Answer (score 2):

Numba now offers [Typed Lists](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#typed-list), these accept a list of lists. As far as I can see they still need to be appended individually though (because the TypedList.extend method doesn't accept LofL). This leads to:

```
from numba.typed import List  # As per the docs, since it's in beta, it needs to be imported explicitly

lol = [[1, 10, 100], [0, 50, 75], [1, 50, 150], [0, 10, 100], [0, 200, 300], [0, 15, 150]]

nb_list = List()
for lst in lol:
    nb_list.append(lst)

coalesce(nb_list)
```

Comment: It needs additional conversion for type of inner lists. Now it is resulting in a list of reflected lists.

Answer (score 1):

Numba as of 0.44 does not support list of lists as inputs to functions in `nopython` mode. See:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#list-reflection

The warnings you are seeing when using `jit` are related to the fact that falling back to object mode, but in future releases of numba, this will raise an error rather than falling back. See:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

If you can convert your input to a 2D numpy array, then you can get around this limitation.

Comment: then what is with the `float32[:,:]` type hint notation about?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. `float32[:,:]` is a `nb.float32` array with two dimensions, specifically a numpy array.

Comment: From the [docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#signature-specifications) regarding function signatures: `int8[:,:] for a two-dimensional array of 8-bit integers.`  So I do not understand why `njit` can't use this

Comment: Because you are trying to use a list of lists, where the lists are Python lists, as opposed to numpy 2d arrays, which are a different data structure. Numba can handle the latter, but not the former.

Answer (score 0):

*In nopython mode, Numba does not operate on Python objects* ([ref1](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pysupported.html#list-reflection), [ref2](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types)) as it is mentioned by [JoshAdel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794390/13394817), too, and we need to convert them to numba compatible one. [I have answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73988197/13394817), but as it is asked several times and is a good topic, I put an answer here, too. In your prepared example, it seems your inputs will be a list of the same length lists (*uniform structure*), AIK, converting your list to numpy array will be the best choice:

```
ranges = np.array(ranges_list, dtype=np.int32)     # --> int32[:, ::1]
```

but, if you have list of variable-length lists (*nonuniform structure*), IMO, [**awkward**](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward) library will get better performance ([see some benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73988197/13394817)) than converting to list of numpy arrays in a loop, *particularly when we are facing to lots of lists*:

- **Awkward**

```
import awkward as ak

ranges = ak.Array(ranges_list)
```

- **NumPy loop with Numba list**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

nb_list = nb.typed.List
ranges = nb_list(np.fromiter(i, dtype=np.int64) for i in ranges_list)
# ranges = nb_list(np.array(i) for i in ranges_list)  # --> ListType(int32[::1])
```

***All of these ways are compatible with numba in nopython mode.***