# How to set 2d array on jit decorator without numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I'm using Numba library in Python3.

A function's parameter is a 2d array.

I set Numba jit decorators to `list[list[int]]`, but show `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` after run code.

I using `print(numba.typeof(matrix))` to detect parameter type, it return `list(reflected list(int32))` type.

But even if I change decorators to `list[list[numba.int32]]` , not working too.

Code:

```py
from numba import jit

size = 3
matrix = [[0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]


@jit(list[list[int]])
def test(jitmatrix):
    _total = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            _total += jitmatrix[j][i]


test(matrix)
```

Have any idea to set 2d array on jit decorator without numpy library ?

Or it must to use numpy library?

Comment: As I mentioned in a recent answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794390/392949), numba does not support list of lists. What you are passing is not a 2d array in the sense that Numba considers a 2d array. If you were to pass `np.array(matrix)` and drop the type specification in the decorator, numba would be able to interpret it and jit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numba as of 0.44 does not support list of lists as inputs to functions in nopython mode. See:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#list-reflection

In the arguments to `@jit`, numba has no knowledge of `list` and cannot convert it automatically to any numba type. The `TypeError ... subscriptable` error is coming from python itself, because you are trying to access an element of a built-in type (`list` in this case), which is not allowed.

The following would work though:

```
from numba import jit
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

size = 3
matrix = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])


@jit(nopython=True)
# or @jit(nb.int64(nb.int64[:,:]))
def test(jitmatrix):
    _total = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            _total += jitmatrix[j,i]  # note the change in indexing, which is faster

    return _total


test(matrix)
```